# WP is showing wrong image dimensions

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, media, thumbnails, media-settings

Several times over time I changed sizes of thumbnails WP generate when images are uploaded, always setting bigger size.

Recently I set Thumbnail Width 600px width and Medium size Max Width 1800px.
After several hundred images uploaded I realized that I need to set smaller image sizes, I reduced Medium size from 1800px to 1500px for future uploads.

I know that already uploaded images will stay on disk in bigger resolution, and that is fine by me, I do not need to use any plugin to regenerate thumbs again.

Problem:

Word Press now shows that size for images uploaded before is also 1500px width, even real size is 1800px (for an example it shows 1500px x 1000px for image that is 1800px x 1200px).

I changed few times width of future images in Dashboard > Settings > Media and I figured out that if real dimensions of already uploaded images are bigger than what is now set in Media Settings, WP will say that width of those images is the width that is set in Media Settings, even real dimensions are bigger.

You can see screenshot example here: https://postimg.cc/fScS3WKH

This is code I use to get image and its dimensions.

```
$medium_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium'); // Featured image medium size

// To show image dimensions   
echo $medium_image_url[1]; // Show width
echo $medium_image_url[2]; // Show height
```

How to get real image dimension of already uploaded images which dimensions are bigger than one now set in media settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get real image dimension of already uploaded images *which
> dimensions are bigger than one now set in **media settings***?

(Note: The *italic and **bold*** formatting above was added by me.)

[`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) indeed doesn't necessarily return the actual width and height of the **resized** image file, and that the function relies upon the specific image size's max width and height set via the media settings screen (see [wp-admin → Settings → Media](https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-media-screen/)).

Sample test case:

1. I uploaded a 1600px × 1199px image (let's call it `foo-image.jpg`), and the Medium image size's max width was 300px (the default one). So WordPress saved that original image file and generated several thumbnails, and as for the Medium-sized thumbnail, the actual dimension is 300px × 225px and named `foo-image-300x225.jpg`.

   And `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` returned `300` (width) and `225` (height) which is the actual dimension.
2. Then I changed the max width (setting) from 300px to 200px.

   And then `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` returned `200` (width) and `150` (height).

   And that is not actually wrong, but it's just not the actual dimension of the actual thumbnail.

So why so, is because `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` uses [`image_downsize()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_downsize/) which uses [`image_constrain_size_for_editor()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_constrain_size_for_editor/) which scales down the actual/default size of an image and which is the function that returns that "wrong" image dimension (1500px × 1000px in your case, and 200px × 150px in the above test case).

But remember, WordPress performs the scaling for a good reason — "*This is so that the image is a better fit for the editor and theme.*" — copied from the `image_constrain_size_for_editor()`'s function reference.

So if you want to retrieve the actual dimension which are saved in a post metadata (see [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/)), you can first, of course use `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` and access the relevant array items, but a simpler way is using [`image_get_intermediate_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_get_intermediate_size/) — moreover, it includes the image path relative to the uploads directory (`wp-content/uploads`), and the full image URL:

```php
$thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

$medium_image_data = image_get_intermediate_size( $thumbnail_id, 'medium' );
var_dump( $medium_image_data['width'], $medium_image_data['height'], $medium_image_data['url'] );
/* Sample output:
int(300)
int(225)
string(68) "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/foo-image-300x225.jpg"
*/

// Or using wp_get_attachment_metadata(), assuming that sizes.medium exists:
$image_metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $thumbnail_id );
$medium_image_data = $image_metadata['sizes']['medium'];
var_dump( $medium_image_data['width'], $medium_image_data['height'] );
// here, $medium_image_data['url'] is NULL (it's not set)!
```

Note though, that the `image_get_intermediate_size()`'s function reference says: (formatted for brevity, and `$size` is the second parameter for the function)

> The `$size` parameter can be an array with the width and height
> respectively. If the size matches the ‘sizes’ metadata array for width
> and height, then it will be used. *If there is no direct match, then
> the nearest image size **larger than** the specified size will be
> used.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort to perform test to better understand problem in my question. Also thank you for providing great answer. It the meantime, I already created PHP function, getimagesize, to directly read image dimensions from file. But your code is WP function, which works faster. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help! And just to let you know, the actual function which calculates the image's constrained dimension is [`wp_constrain_dimensions()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_constrain_dimensions/), and `wp_constrain_dimensions( 300, 225, 200, 300 )` for example returns `array( 200, 150 )`. Also, WordPress actually comes with an enhanced version of `getimagesize()`, which is [`wp_getimagesize()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_getimagesize/). :)

Answer (score 1):

The width and height attributes on the `img` tag are not there to tell the browser how big the image file is (the intrinsic size), they're there to tell the browser how big the `img` tags DOM node is going to be on the page so that it can lay out the page before the file has loaded and avoid an expensive re-calculation of the pages layout. In fact sometimes a mismatch is desirable, e.g. retina images have double the size of their `img` tag width and height, sometimes even more.

What you're describing is the expected and optimal behaviour as the code specifies the `medium` size. WP will use the smallest size that is as large or larger. This avoids upscaling.

**If you want it to use the intrinsic size/original size of the uploaded image,** or to use the exact image dimensions, then you need to use the `full` image size, or regenerate the images using WP CLI or a plugin.

If instead you had used `wp_get_attachment_image` you would have responsive image attributes added, allowing the browser to size things accordingly. You could even pass in an array of width and height instead of `medium` e.g. `[1500, 1000]`.

Comment: I see that for name of the size, wordpress will try to find sizes in metadata  But If the medium size is 500x500, large size is 1000x1000, full - 1500x1500. And we pass a 700x700 size to wp_get_attachment_image(). which size it will return? full with html attributes 700x700?

Comment: This is not browser rendering layout issue, or responsive images (srcset) issue, (I just made print screen so you can see from image src tag that size of image is 1800x1200, and that WP shows 1500 x 1200 as image attributes. Also I do not wish to regenerate images again, also I do not need to show size, width/height of original/full image (which is 6000x4000 px). I wish to show real dimensions of medium sized image which is 1800 x 1200 to users to see real dimension.

Comment: most likely a large as the medium is too small and it's the closest size that is larger. You asked for the `medium` image size and that's what you got, that is where the width and height values come from. The width and height attributes are not there to tell the browser how large the image is, the browser knows that by reading the image files headers and EXIF data, they're there to tell the browser how much space the DOM node occupies on the page.

Comment: If you want to show the 1800x1200 image, then you need to upload it. Right now you asked for `medium` size and WordPress is behaving correctly, setting the width and height to the width and height defined as `medium`. If you removed the height and width, you would have HTML that no longer validates, layout shifts as the browser no longer knows the height of the image prior to it loading, and reduced performance scores in GTMetrix and Google Lighthouse ( there are possibly SEO implications ).

Comment: If you want WordPress to read in the dimensions of the image from the file instead and ignores what the medium image size is without uploading, then you will have to do that manually from scratch using generic PHP functions. WordPress does not load the image file to read the dimensions, it would be a big performance hit to do this and introduce lots of issues, _especially_ for attachments not hosted locally